# Blazor weird behavior when inserting a new row into Dictionary<DateTime, Item> and render by descending date

Tags: c#, blazor

I need to create a dynamic table with custom components, which allows inserting new rows at the first row of the table.

For this, I have created these components - `Page` component:

```
@page "/test"

<h3>Test</h3>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Score</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Item item in items.Values.OrderByDescending(i => i.date))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.date</td>

                <td>
                    <TestComponent OnValueChanged="(v)=>{ item.Score =  Convert.ToInt32(v); }"
                                           Id="@(item.Id.ToString())"
                                           Item="item.Score"
                                           />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <TestStringComponent   Id="@(item.Id.ToString())"
                                           @bind-Item="item.Name"
                                           />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn" @onclick="Add">Add</button>

@code {
    public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public int? Score { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public bool ShowEdit{ get; set; }
    }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, Item> items = new Dictionary<DateTime, Item>();

    public void Add()
    {
        DateTime nextDate = items.Keys.Max().AddDays(1);
        items.Add(nextDate, new Item { Id = "ID "+(items.Count + 1), date = nextDate, Score = items.Count + 1, Name = "Z"});
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        items.Add(new DateTime(2021, 1, 1), new Item { Id = "ID "+1, Score = null, Name = "A",  date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1) });
        items.Add(new DateTime(2021, 1, 2), new Item { Id = "ID " + 2, Score = 2, Name = "B",  date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 2) });
        items.Add(new DateTime(2021, 1, 3), new Item { Id = "ID " + 3, Score = null, Name = "C",  date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 3) });
        items.Add(new DateTime(2021, 1, 4), new Item { Id = "ID " + 4, Score = 4, Name = "D",  date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 4) });
        items.Add(new DateTime(2021, 1, 5), new Item { Id = "ID " + 5, Score = null, Name = "E",  date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 5) });
    }

}
```

TestStringComponent:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@Item

@code {

    public String? _Item { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public String? Item
    {
        get
        {
            return _Item;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Item)
            {
                if(_Item != null || value != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Id+": "+_Item +"->"+ value);
                }
                _Item = value;
                if (ItemChanged.HasDelegate)
                {
                    ItemChanged.InvokeAsync(_Item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<String?> ItemChanged { get; set; }

}
```

And `TestComponent`:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@Item

@code {

    public double? _Item { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public double? Item
    {
        get
        {
            return _Item;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Item)
            {
                if(_Item != null || value != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Id+": "+_Item +"->"+ value);
                }
                _Item = value;
                if (OnValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                {
                    OnValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_Item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<double?> OnValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

But when I insert into the first row of the table, the values and text are strangely replaced.

When first time render, everything seems correct:

[first time render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66IAN.png)

But when click on the button `<Add>`, things start to get weird, first click:

[first click on the Add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx2EQ.png)

and click again:

[on the Add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en86V.png)

What I see is some empty Score are filled by 0, and Name replaced by "Z".

When I check in the console, the 'set' events are triggered on every cell, which is not good for me since I'm using Entity Framework and, as EF tracks entity changes, this potentially causes data pollution when saving to the database.
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xDvZ.png)

Is there any solution to not fire the 'set' events when insert new row at top of table ? and don't replace values of others cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use iterators in the markup, the renderer can get confused about which bits of the DOM need updating with what.

You need to give the renderer some help by giving the markup for each loop in the foreach uniqueness.  The item will do.

Add `@key="item.Id"` to the `tr`:

```cs
        @foreach (Item item in items.Values.OrderByDescending(i => i.date))
        {
            <tr @key="item.Id">
//...
```

[image]

Comment: `@key="item"` (no .Id) is common and I think it is preferred.

Comment: @HH - I don't believe it matters: it's about uniqueness.  But agree that most people use the loop object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing seems to be related to Blazor's re-rendering behavior and the way you're updating the data in the Add method. When you add a new item at the beginning of the dictionary, it affects the ordering of the items in the subsequent rendering, and the components are re-rendered with the updated data.

1. To address this, you can try the following approach:
2. Change the dictionary ordering logic to use a separate list for
   rendering.
3. Only update the list when adding a new item, leaving the dictionary
   unchanged.

Here's a modified version of your code:

csharp

```
@page "/test"
@using FseFront.Pages.Component
<h3>Test</h3>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Score</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Item item in orderedItems)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.date</td>

                <td>
                    <TestComponent OnValueChanged="(v)=>{ item.Score = Convert.ToInt32(v); }"
                                   Id="@(item.Id.ToString())"
                                   Item="item.Score"
                    />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <TestStringComponent Id="@(item.Id.ToString())" @bind-Item="item.Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn" @onclick="Add">Add</button>

@code {
    // ... (your Item class and inject statements)

    private List<Item> orderedItems = new List<Item>();

    public void Add()
    {
        DateTime nextDate = items.Keys.Max().AddDays(1);
        var newItem = new Item { Id = "ID " + (items.Count + 1), date = nextDate, Score = items.Count + 1, Name = "Z" };

        // Update the ordered list without changing the dictionary
        orderedItems.Insert(0, newItem);

        // Render the new item without re-rendering the entire list
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        // ... (initialize items dictionary)

        // Initialize the ordered list for rendering
        orderedItems = items.Values.OrderByDescending(i => i.date).ToList();
    }
}
```

In this approach, the `orderedItems` list is used for rendering, and when you add a new item, it is inserted at the beginning of this list without modifying the original dictionary. This should prevent unwanted re-renders of the entire table and avoid the issues you're encountering.